# Inappropriate Audit Test: Should I use Data Cache or Output Cache for a complex navigation menu?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I was in the Reopen Vote queue, and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166865/should-i-use-data-cache-or-output-cache-for-a-complex-navigation-menu) question as 'up for re-open'. My understanding of 'Primarily Opinion Based' exactly fits this question: it lacks context that an architecture needs to be reviewed in (is this a 10 user or 10M user app?), is asking the user to choose between two different options and the pros/cons thereof (which could be broad indeed), and includes no discussion of actual code.

From meta/the FAQs it seemed to me that these sort of broad architectural questions ought to be dealt with elsewhere? Should this question really have been 'reopened'? I voted 'Leave Closed' and tripped the audit. Even if this question in particular should stay open, should it really be an audit candidate?